# Having trouble resizing an image in an :after element

Tags: html, css

I want to resize the image in an :after element but nothing seems to work, I finally managed to resize it and style it the way I want it using the `display:flex` but it only works on FireFox. Also whenever I try to put the image in a background or background-image it doesn't display the image at all, no idea what's wrong here.

Here you can see what the website https://tradeideasfx.com/2021/05/16/btc-usd-trade-idea/ it's the "long/short" button at the top of the post. If you view the website on FireFox the buttons look exactly as they should be, but on any other wbsite its all over the place. I appreciate any help in advance.

```css
.post-tags {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.post-tags>.Long {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #03cd08;
  padding: 1px 10px 2px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.post-tags>.Short {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #fc0000;
  padding: 1px 10px 2px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.post-tags>.Short:after {
  content: url(https://tradeideasfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/arrow-icon.png);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 25px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.post-tags>.Long:after {
  content: url(https://tradeideasfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/arrow-icon.png);
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 25px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<span class="post-tags">
        <a rel="tag" href="" class="Long">Long</a> 
        <a rel="tag" href="" class="Short">Short</a>                                                                                         </span>
```